# How to navigate to Custom Page from UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

Github Link - https://github.com/dnlatt/iOS/tree/master/MobileDataUsage2

1. I fetched data from Core Data and passed to MobileDataUsageViewController.swift.

```
let detailVC = segue.destination as! MobileDataDetailsViewController
        detailVC.selectedYear = year
        detailVC.years = years
        detailVC.coreDataYears = coreDataYears
```

2. In that Page, I want to show all of the data in slider format.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pageControl.numberOfPages = coreDataYears.count
        pageControl.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        pageControl.currentPage = 1
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlDidChange(_:)) , for: .valueChanged)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        
    }
```

3. How can I access the index of Core Data Array?  E.g from table, if user select '2018' I need to navigate to page 2 and show the result from page 2. I can set the Page Number in Page View Control Event.

If I click on 2018 from the first screen, it's always navigate to
2019 Data Result. I want to set the correct page & navigate to
correct page. How can I get the index of `selectedYear: Year!` from `coreDataYears: [Year] = []` and navigate to correct page. I can set the variable in below parameter

```
pageControl.currentPage = 1
```

[image]

Now only showing 2019 result which is the first one.

[image]

4. If I swipe around the page, it's always stuck on the bottom. How can I fix the UI layout in ? Also there is extra scroll on the UI.

[image]

Comment: There's a LOT of code in your question. Please could you try to find a way to just provide the relevant code to your problem. Like... where is your selection/navigation code?

Comment: Erm... you say in the title that you are using a `UITableView` but your code is just a `UIScrollView` that you are laying out manually? It would make much more sense to use an actual `UITableView`. Once that's done your entire problem disappears.

Comment: You are making this whole thing a lot harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @Fogmeister,

If I navigate from one table - https://ibb.co/j86kz8k, to another table like this page - https://ibb.co/SKZpRwQ. I don't have any issue at all. 

But due to assignment requirements, I need to display all of the data in Page Control / Pager format and navigate to correct year when user click on year from first screen table. I have edited the question. Thanks & appreciate for your help.

Comment: Hmm... I think you might be better off using a `UIPageViewController` to achieve what you are doing. Have a UITableView that shows the years. Then on tap you can navigate to a `UIPageViewController` which will have the current view controller for just the single year. But have the page view controller able to swipe sideways to previous/next year. You can even have a PageControl with that too. That way you can keep each individual controller small. i.e. just one year data. But build the full feature out of multiple controllers.

Comment: @Fogmeister, Thanks a lot. That's save my life. Managed to completed with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Githublink - https://github.com/dnlatt/iOS/tree/master/MobileDataUsage3

Solved this issue by refactoring the code with UIPageViewController. Details in above Github link.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working 